# Best way to constantly show whats on node queue (Using Bottleneck)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, queue, node-modules

I am using the node package called Bottleneck, and I basically want to have a constant log of all that is running in the queue.

If its possible to run it so that as soon as a job lands on the queue it displays the following in a console window:

```
************ CURRENTLY IN QUEUE **********

Name: name_of_api_called
ID: id_of_call
Priority: priority_given
Weight: weight_given
Recieved: date_and_time_recieved
Status: WAITING / ON QUEUE

Name: name_of_api_called
ID: id_of_call
Priority: priority_given
Weight: weight_given
Recieved: date_and_time_recieved
Status: WAITING / ON QUEUE

******************************************
```

Then as soon as it's completed, it removes it of the queue log. Is there a way of it being constantly monitored so that it has the live queue log. If there are no jobs in the queue then it just displays,

***** NOTHING ON QUEUE *****

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anyone reads this - I just did the following:

** This may not be the most ideal or best solution, but it works for what I needed **

```
const queue = new Array();
const success = new Array();
const error = new Array();
let i = 0;
let j = 0;

// Once the limiter is idle, print out all the stats.
limiter.on("idle", function () {
  // Give it a second to recieve the final success statement
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('************ QUEUE STATS *****************');
    (success.length === 0) ? console.log('NOTHING RUNNING') : console.log(success);
    (error.length === 0) ? console.log('NO ERRORS') : console.log(error);
    console.log('******************************************');
    // Reset variables for next run.
    queue.length = 0;
    success.length = 0;
    error.length = 0;
    i = 0;
  }, 1000);
});


// Show a live status on what is happening in the queue.
limiter.on("queued", function (info) {
  console.log(limiter.counts());
});

// Add the times to each of the id's added to the queue so that we can work out how long each takes
function addToQueue(id, api, company) {
  if (!queue[id]) {
    queue[id] = new Date();
  }
}

// Once successful we take the time the id was added to the queue and then minus it from the time now. Store a string of information to print out later (on idle)
    function addToSuccess(id, api, company) {
      if (queue[id]) {
        const timeToComplete = new Date() - queue[id];
        success[i] = 'ID: ' + id + ' | API: /' + api + ' | Company: ' + company + ' | Status: Completed with Success | Time to complete: ' + timeToComplete / 10000 + ' seconds';
        i++;
      }
    }

    // If there is an error then work out the data and store as an error.
    function addToError(id, api, company) {
      if (queue[id]) {
        const timeToComplete = new Date() - queue[id];
        error[j] = 'ID: ' + id + ' | API: /' + api + ' | Company: ' + company + ' | Status: Error | Time to complete: ' + timeToComplete / 10000 + ' seconds';
        j++;
      }
    }

// in order to get a really random number for the ID to track it (running the api multiple times, so makes it easier to distinguish the id)
    const id = Math.floor(( Math.random() * 1000) * ( Math.random() * 10) / Math.random() * 100);

      const ops = {
        priority: 2,
        id: id
      };

      addToQueue(ops.id, 'api', body.customerId);

      limiter.schedule(ops, () => axios.post(url, body, {
        headers
      })).then((res) => {
        addToSuccess(ops.id, 'api', body.customerId);
        res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(res.data));
      }).catch((error) => {
        addToError(ops.id, 'api', body.customerId);
        res.status(500).send(error);
      });
```